# Java 8 method reference type inference

Tags: java, generics, java-8

I'm confused by a bit of Java 8's type inference.  The following code:

```
private static <T> Function<Iterable<? extends T>, Iterator<? extends T>>
    toIterator() {
  return Iterable<? extends T>::iterator;
}
```

breaks with the compile error

```
error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
    return Iterable<? extends T>::iterator;
           ^
    method iterator in interface Iterable<T#2> cannot be applied to given types
      required: no arguments
      found: Iterable<? extends T#1>
      reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
  where T#1,T#2 are type-variables:
    T#1 extends Object declared in method <T#1>toIterator()
    T#2 extends Object declared in interface Iterable
```

whereas removing the explicit generic

```
private static <T> Function<Iterable<? extends T>, Iterator<? extends T>>
    toIterator() {
  return Iterable::iterator;
}
```

works, as does the old-school anonymous inner class

```
private static <T> Function<Iterable<? extends T>, Iterator<? extends T>>
    toIterator() {
  return new Function<Iterable<? extends T>, Iterator<? extends T>>() {
    @Override
    public Iterator<? extends T> apply(Iterable<? extends T> iterable) {
      return iterable.iterator();
    }
  };
}
```

Can anyone suggest what might be going on here?

Comment: My best guess at this point is that Java 8 thinks that the two `<? extends T>` wildcards are different and won't consider the possibility that the iterable _is_ the argument.

Comment: I don't think that is valid notation. The left hand side of `::` shouldn't have type arguments. Actually...I'm going to review this statement.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis In fact that compiles fine.

Comment: @RohitJain What does?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis The notation `Iterable<? extends T>::iterator;`

Comment: @RohitJain In which context though? That's OP's problem, that it doesn't compile.

Comment: @LouisWasserman Your guess seems correct to me. Since compiler would replace the wildcards with placeholders. The one in `Function` type would be like - `Iterator<T#1>` and the one you're returning would be take `Iterator<T#2>` as parameter. That is a mismatch.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I'm saying about your 2nd statement. Left side of `::` can have type arguments (at least that is what I see after compiling that on my machine). It doesn't complain about the method reference usage, but only the type mismatch.

Comment: @Rohit What expression are you compiling where that notation works? What is the type mismatch that it complains about? What compiler?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Java 1.8 from Oracle. The type mismatch is the same error OP is getting. I'm compiling the same method.

Comment: @RohitJain OP's error states that the `iterator` method expects no arguments, but found one argument of type `Iterator<? extends T>`. This is like having `void foo()` and calling `foo("whatever")`

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Whoa!! That is a strange error. Why is it considering it as argument to `iterator()`? Really strange. Didn't look closely earlier :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `<? extends T>` is wrong because for Generic invocations with explicit type arguments you have to specify complete types, not wildcard types.

If you simply use

```
private static <T> Function<Iterable<? extends T>, Iterator<? extends T>>
    toIterator() {
  return Iterable::iterator;
}
```

Java will infer the type for you.

---

A solution would be:

```
private static <T> Function<Iterable<T>, Iterator<? extends T>> toIterator() {
  return Iterable<T>::iterator;
}
```

though it is not clear what the advantage of widening the `Function`’s return type to `? extends T` shall be. For practical uses,

```
private static <T> Function<Iterable<T>, Iterator<T>> toIterator() {
  return Iterable<T>::iterator;
}
```

will be the most useful method signature. For this, the inferring `Iterable::iterator` still works as well.

---

Regarding the compiler error message, this seems just to be a bug in the error reporting which applies always when a method reference to a non-`static` method has a type mismatch. It can be reproduced even by the simple statement:

```
Consumer<Object> c=String::getClass;
```

which produces the error message:

```
error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
Consumer<Object> c=String::getClass;
                   ^
method getClass in class Object cannot be applied to given types
  required: no arguments
  found: Object
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Note that references to `static` methods get the right error message:

```
Consumer<Object> c=Class::forName;
```

produces:

```
error: incompatible types: invalid method reference
Consumer<Object> c=Class::forName;
                   ^
incompatible types: Object cannot be converted to String
```

Comment: Wouldn't your first snippet indicate a generic method `iterator`? This is an instance method that depends on the type parameter of the declaring type.

Comment: You are trying to use generic method of a raw type, that is simply useless.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: where do you see a raw type in my answer? Method references will always use type inference to get the right Generic type.

Comment: @Holger `Iterable::<T>iterator;` is using raw type `Iterable`. Generic type would be like - `Iterable<T>::iterator`

Comment: @Holger Type argument on left is for generic type, and the one used on right side is to give type arguments for method being invoked.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: So why do you think my code compiles without any error in Netbeans then?

Comment: @Holger It would compile fine. Just that it might give you warning, of unused type argument `T`, if you've configured your NetBeans like so.

Comment: @Rohit Jain: well, I didn’t get a warning but you’re right, I can put anything into it. That should be an *error* then…

Comment: The right hand side of the `::` is for generic methods. `iterator` is not a generic method. It's like doing `System.out.<Object>println()`, you'll just get a warning that it is unused.

Comment: Also, your first statement seems wrong, because they would get the same (type of) error if they used `<T>` instead of `<? extends T>`.

Comment: @Sotirios Delimanolis: Before Java 7, `System.out.<Object>println()` gave an error, tried with both, Oracle jdk and eclipse. Is there a reason for allowing it now and just producing a warning (sometimes).

Comment: I don't understand your last section - both error messages seem reasonable there.

Comment: @Paul Bellora: The first one is *not* reasonable because the claim “actual and formal argument lists differ in length” is wrong as the argument list does *not* differ in length. This can be simply illustrated by fixing the first example’s code changing it to `Consumer<String> c=String::getClass;` or `Consumer<Object> c=Object::getClass;` as it is only a type mismatch but not a number mismatch. It’s important to understand that the receiver object for an instance method counts as an argument when comparing with a functional signature.